# Use variable as operator in if test

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use a variable as an operator inside an `if` test.

```
if [[ $action = "active" ]];then
       operator="-le"
fi

if [[ $Apps $operator 100 ]];then
    echo "No of apps $Apps"
fi
```

I am getting syntax error near `

Comment: Near what? Near `? There's no backtick in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to `[`, which won't seen its arguments until after the shell has expanded all the parameters. `[[` has to be fully parsed before `$operator` is expanded, and it needs to see an actual operator.

```
if [ "$Apps" "$operator" 100 ]; then 
  echo "No of apps $Apps"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try nested `if` operators?

```
if [ "$action" = "active" ]
   then if [ "$Apps" -eq 100 ]
....
```

Comment: Thanks for response .. Because of other code.. i have to do it seperately .. But single bracket worked